# Mysql error #1054 - Unknown column 'Y' in 'where clause' on Update

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have a table 'client' where a column 'wipes' is currently filled with Y or N. I want to change Y and N to 1 and 0. I am trying this query and getting the error "Unknown column 'Y' in 'where clause'"
I have tried every combination of with backticks, without backticks, single quotes, etc... Why does it think that 'Y" is a column?

```
UPDATE client
SET wipes = `1`
WHERE wipes = `Y`;
```

Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use a single quote like

```
UPDATE client
SET wipes = 1
WHERE wipes = 'Y';

UPDATE `client` SET `wipes` = CASE
WHEN wipes= 'Y' THEN 1
WHEN wipes = 'N' THEN 0
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I Got it, slightly stupid. It should be

```
WHERE wipes LIKE 'Y';
```

that worked. I don't know if it would be the same in every sql version. But I'm using phpMyadmin.